# twitter: search hashtags in a twitter list

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

i'm trying to use 'Twitter Search Widget' [here](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search) searching an #hashtag in a '[Twitter List](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists)', but i can't fix the exact query. Someone did it before me?
Thanks in advance, sorry for my poor english.
Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to directly search twitter lists using the widget.  If you look at the "operators" link on this page:
https://twitter.com/#!/search-home

You can use "from:userid OR from:userid2 #hashtag" to search for #hashtag tweets from specific users, and hashtags work fine - so you could manually build a search for a list if you wanted.

You can see what operators search can take by looking at the advanced search page here:
https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced

Comment: Thank you Kirsten, seems the only way to solve this problem. I'll try. Francesco

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you're trying to search for tweets containing a specific #hashtag, authored uniquely by certain list members?

If this is the case, say for example your looking for the hashtag #COVID19 relayed only by @Twitter's list of official Twitter accounts, you could do it with the following Twitter search query:

```
#COVID19 list:84839422
```

[Try it...](https://twitter.com/search?q=%20%23COVID19%20list%3A84839422&src=typed_query&f=live)

The structure is quite simple...

```
[#hashtag] list:[list_id]
```

You can find list IDs by looking at the URL line in the browser when opening lits on Twitter. For example, here is the URL of @Twitter's official accounts liss:

```
https://twitter.com/i/lists/84839422
```

The list ID are the digits after the last `/`.